# External JS library for angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular

I have read all the topic about this subject but i don't understand.
I think that i need an example to understand. 
I'm a new learner in angular, i wouldlike to do an mathematical application for mobule with ionic. 
So after two weeks when i read a lot and a lot of tutorial, documenations, forum, about angular, i have try to install the two library Mathjax (that it permit to write mathematical character in HTML), and jsxgraph  (that it permit to create geometry figure). 
But really i don't understrand how. 
For the moment i just try with mathjax and all i have succed to do is "npm install mathjax" that it install in node_modules directory Mathjax.js

But now ? What should i do ?

Thnaks in advance for your help, and sorry for my very bad english, i'm french :D

Best regards

Comment: You should try, post the code with a technical problem here, and get some help. SO solves technical problems, not `what I should do` questions, sorry... :(

Comment: Thanks for your advise but i'm really loose. I simply just know with what begin... for the moment it's just a blank project in i try to use this library...

Comment: Well, just set up a project and try it. We cannot turn on your computer and your willpower for you...

Answer (score 0):

If those two libraryies can be found in [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) you just have to install and import them.

`npm install js-library-name  --save`

`import { moduleName } from 'js-library-name';`

And if you dont find those libraries in npm you can add Javascript files to the `global scope` via the `scripts` option inside your project's build target options in **angular.json**. These will be loaded exactly as if you had added them in a `<script>` tag inside *index.html*.

Comment: Yes the two can be found in npm, for example the first i have do the npm install mathjax --save. it's easy to use this in a normal html page (with importing js script) but i don't understand how can i do with angular (i'm ashaming because, it's evident that is easy, but they are a lot of subtility that i not yet understand) in all case thank you a lot to take your time in oder to help me.